# Need to erase the stroke between start & end points of a path in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, stroke

I opened a PSD in Illustrator. The file has a path in it, but when given a stroke, it joins the ends of the path, which I do not want. I do not want a closed stroke, instead I want an open stroke.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this behavior, but I can't.  If your path is really as simple as it looks, just redraw it in AI

Answer (score 5):

This happens because your path is being imported from Photoshop as a Compound Shape. Strokes, or any appearance attributes, are applied to the whole shape.

To stop this from happening you need to release the compound shape from the Pathfinder panel's options dropdown:

[image]

You can find out more about Compound Shapes here:

- [**Adobe Illustrator Help - Compound Shapes**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html#compoundshapes)